# How to retrieve all but Renew Account for a system admin

Tags: php, session

Please, I'm new to PHP and I'm building a subscription-based ecommerce site. I've been able to customize the pages such that they look different based on who's browsing what, but I'd like to take the Renew Account off the admin page since they don't have to subscribe.

I've been struggling all day. Please, could someone show me how it could be achieved?
Below is the snippet:

```
<?php // Show the user info or the login form:
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    // Show basic user options:
    echo '<div class="title">
                <h4>Manage Your Account</h4>
            </div>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="renew.php" title="Renew Your Account">Renew Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="change_password.php" title="Change Your Password">Change Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="favorites.php" title="View Your Favorite Pages">Favorites</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.php" title="View Your History">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="recommendations.php" title="View Your Recommendations">Recommendations</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            ';

    // Show admin options, if appropriate:
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_admin'])) {
        echo '<div class="title">
                    <h4>Administration</h4>
                </div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="add_page.php" title="Add a Page">Add Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="add_pdf.php" title="Add a PDF">Add PDF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Blah">Blah</a></li>
                </ul>
                ';      
    }

} else { // Show the login form:

    require ('login_form.inc.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the question? I don't understand what you're asking. What isn't working the way you would like it to?

Comment: I don't want the Renew Account to show under the admin side

Comment: See the answer given below.

Comment: What is the status of the question? Given the answer; does it work or not?

Comment: It doesn't work. Could there be another way?

Comment: You have to comment under the answer; they don't know if it worked or not. Their logic seems right to me. But I just noticed that they did make a mistake in their `$_SESSSION` though. Edit: which was fixed.

Comment: Show your code and any errors after trying the below answer.

Comment: Your logic is a bit off. What you have now will show everything inside `if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {...}` if the user id session is set. You need to separate those. You could also use what is called a "ternary operator" http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

Comment: Let me try the ternary operator then

Comment: @jessebrite I've added an answer that you could have a look at below Jesse.

Comment: Trying that right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to first check if the user admin session is set, to which I added the same conditional value for in the first conditional statement.

If it is set, then assign an empty value for what I named as `$renew`, with an `else{}` with the value that I removed from your existing `<li></li>`.

The first two session arrays here are only representational values of course.

I concatenated the `'.$renew.'` variable in the menu.

**Note:** Make sure that the session was started using [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) inside all pages using sessions; that is not known.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 123;
$_SESSION['user_admin'] = "john";

if (isset($_SESSION['user_admin'])) {

$renew = '';

} else {

$renew = '<li><a href="renew.php" title="Renew Your Account">Renew Account</a></li>';

}


if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    // Show basic user options:
    echo '<div class="title">
                <h4>Manage Your Account</h4>
            </div>
            <ul>
            '.$renew.'
            <li><a href="change_password.php" title="Change Your Password">Change Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="favorites.php" title="View Your Favorite Pages">Favorites</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.php" title="View Your History">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="recommendations.php" title="View Your Recommendations">Recommendations</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            ';

    // Show admin options, if appropriate:
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_admin'])) {
        echo '<div class="title">
                    <h4>Administration</h4>
                </div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="add_page.php" title="Add a Page">Add Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="add_pdf.php" title="Add a PDF">Add PDF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Blah">Blah</a></li>
                </ul>
                ';      
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems not to work. I The Renew Account doesn't show, but I keep seeing the same log admin content as though I haven't logged out. I don't know what could possibly be the cause. PS I have session_start () in all pages that require session

Comment: @jessebrite What I posted worked for me. Make sure that caching isn't an issue here and/or that the previous session doesn't still exist and needs to be destroyed and a logout method does use the function to destroy it.

Comment: @FunkyFortNiner I finally got it to work! I removed the two session variables as seen in your code since they'll be coming from other pages. Your code is a life saver. Thanks@ColbyBoren as well. You guys are awesome

Comment: @FunkyFortyNiner How's it done? Is it different from upvoting?

Comment: @jessebrite There's a gray'ish checkmark just under the up/down arrows that you tick. When it turns green, it is marked as accepted and the question is then marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
If(!isset($_SESSION['user_admin'])) {echo '<li><a href="renew.php" title="Renew Your Account">Renew Account</a></li>'; }
```

This way if it the session variable for admin is set the echo won't occur.

Comment: `$_SESSSION` isn't valid. Edit: This as per the original answer https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53328105/1

Comment: Yeah I fixed it. Thanks